# EXC_BAD_ACCESS with ARC-based app, no ideas

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, exc-bad-access

I'm stuck on this bad memory access error. I've tried to look for "zombies" as I read in other posts, but with no luck! I'm using automatic reference counting.

The only thing that makes me suspect is that I changed the project folder name yesterday, and I've got a lot of errors, which after I fixed. Then when the project was working again, I did no particular changes to the code, so I really don't understand.

This happens after clicking on a button, even if the method call inside the button's `IBAction` is commented, I still got the error.

I had problems with the .pch file, plist, relocated all the folders of the project to the new path (this was done yesterday).

```
* thread #1: tid = 0xadfee, 0x0000000000000000, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread, stop    reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
   frame #0: 0x0000000000000000
   frame #1: 0x00007fff8c6ab460 AppKit`-[NSUserDefaultsController _invokeSingleSelector:withArguments:onKeyPath:] + 99
    frame #2: 0x00007fff8c6e9c31 AppKit`-[NSObject(_NSBinderKeyValueCodingAdditions) _invokeSelector:withArguments:onKeyPath:] + 745
    frame #3: 0x00007fff8c311cbd AppKit`-[NSBinder _invokeSelector:withArguments:onKeyPath:ofObject:mode:raisesForNotApplicableKeys:] + 234
frame #4: 0x00007fff8c3121d0 AppKit`-[NSBinder invokeSelector:withArguments:forBinding:error:] + 173
frame #5: 0x00007fff8c2e2f1e AppKit`-[NSActionBinder _invokeSelector:withArguments:forBinding:] + 131
frame #6: 0x00007fff8c2e375f AppKit`-[NSActionBinder _performActionWithCommitEditing:didCommit:contextInfo:] + 314
frame #7: 0x00007fff8c6ed096 AppKit`_NSSendCommitEditingSelector + 267
frame #8: 0x00007fff8c39a288 AppKit`-[NSController _controllerEditor:didCommit:contextInfo:] + 182
frame #9: 0x00007fff91655d4c CoreFoundation`__invoking___ + 140
frame #10: 0x00007fff91655bb4 CoreFoundation`-[NSInvocation invoke] + 308
frame #11: 0x00007fff916f87f6 CoreFoundation`-[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 54
frame #12: 0x00007fff89b38117 Foundation`__NSFireDelayedPerform + 333
frame #13: 0x00007fff916d17a4 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
frame #14: 0x00007fff916d12df CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1151
frame #15: 0x00007fff9174296a CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoTimers + 298
frame #16: 0x00007fff9168cb55 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1525
frame #17: 0x00007fff9168c325 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
frame #18: 0x00007fff8ccd7b1d HIToolbox`RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 226
frame #19: 0x00007fff8ccd7793 HIToolbox`ReceiveNextEventCommon + 173
frame #20: 0x00007fff8ccd76ca HIToolbox`_BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 65
frame #21: 0x00007fff8bf5a5fe AppKit`_DPSNextEvent + 1434
frame #22: 0x00007fff8bf59c4b AppKit`-[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 122
frame #23: 0x00007fff8bf4dbbc AppKit`-[NSApplication run] + 553
frame #24: 0x00007fff8bf38a53 AppKit`NSApplicationMain + 940
frame #25: 0x0000000100001dd2 Mp3_Radar`main(argc=3, argv=0x00007fff5fbff838) + 34 at main.m:13
frame #26: 0x0000000100001da4 Mp3_Radar`start + 52
```

(lldb)

Edit: I've found the problem. 
The button binding "target" was set to user defaults controller, unchecking this did the trick. Probably I accidentally activated that option and then continued to do some stuff and forgot about that change.. Anyway thanks to everybody who tried to help me. 
I know that my grammar is not perfect, is that a good reason to place a negative vote to the question? I was just trying to solve a problem, and english is not my native language.
Anyway, I hope that this post can help someone else!

Comment: It would appear from your stack trace that you're calling some method using an NSTimer. It may be that the object that the timer is trying to perform some selector on has been deallocated, causing the bad access.

Comment: I'm using FileSystem Events to track changes in a folder,maybe it uses a timer (I'm guessing). In the fsevents stream initialize method i have "runLoop". I don't use any other timer. Its strange, yesterday the same code was working..

Comment: Do you have NSZombies enabled in your scheme? with that you should at least be able to tell what class of object your zombie is

Comment: Running Zombies in Instruments will not only tell you what class the zombie is, but where it was allocated and all the retains, releases and autoreleases that occurred on that object.

Comment: Yes NSZombies are activated. But i've got no alert.  I'm thinking about moving all the files to a new project, but would be better to find the cause to avoid this in the future! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked that the button is hooked up the the correct IBAction? You said you did some renaming and moving around of files. It sometimes happens that the connection gets lost and you only know about it when clicking on a button tries to send the action message to an invalid selector.

Comment: Yes,all the connections are good. In fact the IBAction is called, and after doing all the stuff, crashes (but i can see that it works, because it moves some files as it should).

Comment: Have you tried putting breakpoints in your code to try and narrow down the part where the crash occurs?

Comment: That's the problem! I've tried to do step by step debugging, but the error occours while the debugger is stepping into assembler code, wich I don't understand very well.

Comment: Place breakpoints in your code before the crash happens, and then go forward step by step. When it goes into assembly you'll have an idea of where things are going wrong.

Comment: `0x7fff8db8ea35:  movq   -358281140(%rip), %rsi    ; "_installAutoreleasePoolsOnCurrentThreadIfNecessary"
0x7fff8db8ea3c:  callq  *-359735346(%rip)         ; (void *)0x00007fff89872080: objc_msgSend
0x7fff8db8ea42:  movq   (%r13), %rdi
0x7fff8db8ea46:  movq   -358281141(%rip), %rsi    ; "run"
`

This is the last part before the app crashes. I don't know what I can do with this. 
What I did was commenting all the code inside the `IBAction`, then debugging into assembly I can only see mouse related events (probably the mouse down event on the button) and finally this. Nothing else. :)

Comment: I've edited the post, found the solution, was a binding problem. Thanks man

Comment: @Benz As you're new, and I see you've not accepted any answers or cast any votes; if an answer has helped you it's general practice to accept it by clicking on the tick under the number.